# Counting days between two dates

Tags: qt, qdatetime

I tried to make a program with Qt that counts how many days are between two dates. The problem is that I am novice in Qt and I haven't got it working.

I guess `QDateTime` is easy, but I don't understand the structure of a program.

Could somebody please make an example for me. Just a simple program that shows how many days it is until Christmas for example.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you read Qt tutorials from Qt official documentation?

Comment: Have you looked through all the [examples](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/all-examples.html) provided by Qt already?

Answer (score 21):

Your problem is very simple.

Create console application in QtCreator, and edit your `main.cpp` this way:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDate>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    // get current date
    QDate dNow(QDate::currentDate());
    // create other date
    //  by giving date 12.21.2012 (joke about end of the world)
    QDate dEndOfTheWorld(2012, 12, 21);
    qDebug() << "Today is" << dNow.toString("dd.MM.yyyy")
             << "Days to end of the world: "
             << dNow.daysTo(dEndOfTheWorld);

    return a.exec();
}
```

And you'll got output like:

> Today is "18.12.2012" Days to end of the world:  3

**P.S.** But my advice to you is learn C++ (add to your favorite this topic -- [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)), and then learn Qt (I recommend [C++ GUI Programming with Qt 4 by Jasmin Blanchette & Mark Summerfield](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132354160) and Summerfields other books).
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use

```
qint64 QDateTime::toMSecsSinceEpoch () const
```

This returns the datetime as the number of milliseconds that have passed since 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000

As there is no way to directly find timeSpan. Convert your 2 dateTime objects into milliseconds, subtract and convert into days, hours, mins, secs using mathematical manipulation.

Comment: Thanks! But my main problem is the structure of program. The various different files and such. How to make the program with qtcreator for example to Nokia N9...

Answer (score 0):

For those who work with `QDateTime`, and because of the definition of `QDateTime::daysTo(const QDateTime &other)` :

> [...] The number of days is counted as the number of times midnight is reached between this datetime to the other datetime. This means that a 10 minute difference from 23:55 to 0:05 the next day counts as one day.

I clearly recommend to do that :

```
    int dateDelay = QDateTime::currentDateTime().secsTo(datetimeGoal);
    int secs = dateDelay % 60;
    int minNum = (dateDelay-secs) / 60;
    int mins = minNum % 60;
    int hourNum = (minNum-mins) / 60;
    int hours = hourNum % 24;
    int days = (hourNum - hours) / 24;

    QString goalStr = "We will reach the special event in : "
       +QString::number(days)+" days "+QString::number(hours)+" hours "
       +QString::number(mins)+" mins "+QString::number(secs)+" secs ";
```